# How to fix Laravel Group by error in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

6

Am facing Laravel Group By Error.
I can solve this by change

```
'strict' => true, to 'strick'=>false
```

Here is my sql query :

```
select `employee_id`, `section_id`, `out_time` from `attendances` where `employee_id` is not null and `out_time` is null group by `section_id`
```

its working at sql command.
When i tried to run with laravel by this code  its showing error . 

Laravel Controller Code Below :

```
$attendances = DB::table('attendances')
            ->select('employee_id','section_id','out_time')
            ->where('employee_id', '!=', null)
            ->where('out_time', null)
            ->groupBy('section_id')->get();
```

After run this code its showing error, error below :

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'erp.attendances.employee_id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `employee_id`, `section_id`, `out_time` from `attendances` where `employee_id` is not null and `out_time` is null group by `section_id`)
```

How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the values as collection and then grouping the results, i.e use [Collection's `groupBy()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-groupby) instead of query builder.

So your queries should be:

```
$attendances = DB::table('attendances')
        ->select('employee_id','section_id','out_time')
        ->where('employee_id', '!=', null)
        ->where('out_time', null)
        ->get()
        ->groupBy('section_id');
```